# Order a linked list alphabetically by name

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am having an issue organizing a linked list alphabetically.  I am reading the names in from a text file and storing them into a linked list.  The problem I am having is how to sort them alphabetically.  If anybody could point me in the right direction that would be amazing.  The idea is to get the value of the first 3 letters in each name and compare them to the first 3 in the next name.  But where would I compare the letters together?

Here is the LinkedListNode class:

```
public class LinkedListNode
{

    private String data;
    private LinkedListNode next;


    public LinkedListNode(String data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public String getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public LinkedListNode getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(LinkedListNode n)
    {
        next = n;
    }
}
```

Here is the LinkedList file with the main method:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinkedList {

    public LinkedListNode head;
    String fname;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Names.txt"));
            LinkedList l = new LinkedList();    
            int i = 1;
            while(scan.hasNext()) {
                String s = scan.nextLine();
                l.insertBack(s);
                i++;
            }
            System.out.print(l.showList());
        }


    public LinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
    }

    public void insertBack(String data){

        if(head == null){
            head = new LinkedListNode(data);
        }else{
            LinkedListNode newNode = new LinkedListNode(data);
            LinkedListNode current = head;
            while(current.getNext() != null){
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            current.setNext(newNode);
        }
    }

    public String showList(){
        int i = 0, j;
        String retStr = "List nodes:\n";
        LinkedListNode current = head;
        while(current != null){
            i++;
            retStr += "Node " + i + ": " + current.getData() + "\n";
            current = current.getNext();

        }

        return retStr;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep the `List` sorted at all times then you can base the algorithm on an insertion sort. If you just want to sort once then just use a standard algorithm like quicksort.

Comment: If have to program the sorting part yourself, then I believe bubble sort should not be difficult to implement.

Comment: Would i call the sort in the showList function though, after all the nodes are built and when the list is being printed?

Comment: You need to give us more information. Read my comment. Do you want the list sorted at all times or do you want to sort it at the end?

Comment: I would like to sort it all the times.  Like make it happen just once when the list is initially built and printed out, then remain sorted.

Comment: In that case you need to do an insertion sort when you add elements - see Cruncher's answer for an idea of where to begin.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm not sure how efficient quicksort would be without random access on the list.

Comment: @Cruncher true, maybe mergesort would be a better choice. In any case, I think the OP wants to guarantee that the `List` is sorted at all times so your approach is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Some pseudo code for you:

```
OUTER:
for word in file
    node = head
    while node.next
        if word > node.word
             node.next
        else
             Node temp = new Node(word)
             temp.next = word.next
             node.next = temp
             continue OUTER
    node.next = new Node(word)
```

This is an as-you-go insertion sort. After every insert the file will be sorted. Or you could use other sorting algorithms after you read all of the data

if it's `if word > node.word` this part you're having trouble with, the [String#compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) method will be useful

Answer (score 0):

To do easy comparisons, your nodes should implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/).  The base Java libraries tend to rely upon this for easy sorting.

The Comaprable interface will require you to implement compareTo (see below).

```
public int <LinkedListNode> compareTo(LinkedListNode n){
  //Case insensitively compare the first 3 characters of the two nodes
  String myHead = data.substring(0,3).toLowerCase();
  String comparableHead = n.data.substring(0,3).toLowerCase();

  return (myHead.compareTo(comparableHead));

}
```

If you use a standard List structure like, ArrayList, the Collections.sort(list) will be able to use this method to order your list.

And here's an insertion sort based "insert" function for your runTime, using this comparable.

```
public void insert(String data){
    LinkedListNode newNode = new LinkedListNode(data);
    if(head == null){
        head = newNode;
    }else{
        LinkedListNode current = head;
        LinkedListNode prev;

        //This is missing some key edge cases, but it inserts properly in the general case.  You'll have to add to it to handle things like running off the list, or this needing to be inserted before the head.
        while(current.getNext() != null){
            if(current.compareTo(newNode)<0){
              newNode.setNext(current);
              prev.setNext(newNode);
              break;
            }
            prev = current;
            current = current.getNext();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably the OP's `LinkedList` may have to `implements List` for that, no?

Comment: Note that String's default comparator is lexographic sorting, meaning that 'a' != 'A'.

YOu can provide a new comparator which is case insensitive if you need to

Comment: @BoristheSpider You're absolutely correct that OP would have to make use of an existing collection or implement the interface to use Collections.sort.  However, implementing Comparable<Node> could prove valuable for the insertion sort mechanism.  The Comparator could compare only the first three characters, thus preventing the need to .substring in the insertion logic.

Comment: updated to with code snippet to demonstrate the use case of Comparable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using *Collections.sort(list)*

Also, for comparing, you can use *compareTo* function under Comparable Interface

Comment: Is OP's LinkedList truly a [`list`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)?