# Sorting a Linked List in alphabetical order

Tags: java, sorting, singly-linked-list

I have an assignment where I have to make my one linked list that holds a person name and their vehicle plate number that enters in a compound. but I need to sort the list in alphabetical order by using the license plate number(example: ABS1234). I have been doing some research on sorting for example merge sort or using the collection.sort, but can't wrap my head around it. it will be awesome if I can get a little push on how to do this. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Node {
//data fields
public String regPlate; // Registration Plate
public String firstName;
public String lastName;

//refrence link
public Node link;

//default constructor
public Node()
{
    regPlate = "";
    firstName = "";
    lastName = "";
}//end of constructor.

}//end of node class
```

this is the Node class that i created.

```
public class LinkedList {

Node head;
Node tail;
Node current;
int listLength;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

//default constructor
public LinkedList () 
{
    head = null;
    listLength = 0;
}

//inserting new node in the beginning of the list
public void insertFirst(String fN, String lN, String rP)
{

    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.firstName = fN;
    newNode.lastName = lN;
    newNode.regPlate = rP;

    //make newNode point to the first node in the life
    newNode.link = head;

    //makes head point to the new first node
    head = newNode;

    if(head == null)
        tail = newNode;

    ++listLength;
}//end of insertFirst


public void displayDataLog()
{
    Node current;

    current = head;

    while(current != null)
    {
        System.out.print("\n FullName: " + current.firstName + " " + current.lastName +
                        "\n Registration Plate Number: " + current.regPlate);

        current = current.link;
    }

}//end of display vehicles

public void totalVehicles()
{
    System.out.print("\n Total Vehicle on the campus: " + listLength);
}//end of total vehicles


}//end of linked list
```

Comment: What is a "BlinkList"? Did you just mean "Linked List"?

Comment: yeah linked list

Comment: Do you have to implement the sorting algorithm? Or can you use Collection.sort?

Comment: i can use collection.sort but not sure how to use it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order a linked list alphabetically by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776700/order-a-linked-list-alphabetically-by-name)

Comment: I had seen this but did not understand it what so ever. Thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Collection.sort() this should be fairly easy.

First, you need to create your own `Comparator`, since the default one won't work (you want to order by a specific field, the license plate).

```
class NodeComparator implements Comparator<Node> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Node n1, Node n2) {
        return n1.regPlate.compareTo(n2.regPlate);
    }
}
```

---

Now you have your Comparator, just use it, here is an example I used (created an ArrayList and introduced every element of the list there):

```
private static LinkedList sortList(LinkedList list) {
    // I use an ArrayList so I can just use Collections.sort
    LinkedList sortedList = new LinkedList();
    Node current = list.head;
    ArrayList<Node> array = new ArrayList<Node>();

    while (current != null) {
        array.add(current);
        current = current.link;
    }
    array.sort(new NodeComparator());

    for (int i = array.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sortedList.insertFirst(array.get(i));
    }

    return sortedList;
}
```

I made a few changes that will, most likely, be easy to adapt to your own program. You can see the full working program here: https://code.sololearn.com/cgzN5sQOI8uW.

---

---

The entire the code, for the sake of completion (and just in case the link stops working):

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*; 
import java.io.*;

class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.insertFirst("Robert", "Rodriguez", "RB123");
        list.insertFirst("Andrew", "Andrews", "AB123");
        list.insertFirst("Thomas", "Thomson", "TB123");

        System.out.println(list); // Prints unordered list, opposite order as they were introduced, since they were introduced from the beggining of the list.

        LinkedList sorted = sortList(list);
        System.out.println("\n"+sorted);
    }

    private static LinkedList sortList(LinkedList list) {
        // I use an ArrayList so I can just use Collections.sort
        LinkedList sortedList = new LinkedList();
        Node current = list.head;
        ArrayList<Node> array = new ArrayList<Node>();

        while (current != null) {
            array.add(current);
            current = current.link;
        }
        System.out.println("\nTemp Array:");
        System.out.println(array);

        array.sort(new NodeComparator());

        System.out.println("\nTemp Array (now sorted):");
        System.out.println(array);

        for (int i = array.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            sortedList.insertFirst(array.get(i));
        }

        return sortedList;
    }
}

class NodeComparator implements Comparator<Node> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Node n1, Node n2) {
        return n1.regPlate.compareTo(n2.regPlate);
    }
}

class Node {
    //data fields
    public String regPlate; // Registration Plate
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

    //refrence link
    public Node link;

    //default constructor
    public Node()
    {
        regPlate = "";
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
    }//end of constructor.

    public String toString() {
        return this.regPlate;
    }



}//end of node class

class LinkedList {

    Node head;
    Node tail;
    Node current;
    int listLength;

    //default constructor
    public LinkedList () 
    {
        head = null;
        listLength = 0;
    }

    //inserting new node in the beginning of the list
    public void insertFirst(String fN, String lN, String rP)
    {

        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.firstName = fN;
        newNode.lastName = lN;
        newNode.regPlate = rP;

        insertFirst(newNode);
    }//end of insertFirst

    public void insertFirst(Node newNode) {
        //make newNode point to the first node in the life
        newNode.link = head;

        //makes head point to the new first node
        head = newNode;

        if(head.link == null)
            tail = newNode;

        ++listLength;
    }

    public void displayDataLog()
    {
        Node current;

        current = head;

        while(current != null)
        {
            System.out.print("\n FullName: " + current.firstName + " " + current.lastName +
                            "\n Registration Plate Number: " + current.regPlate);

            current = current.link;
        }

    }//end of display vehicles

    public void totalVehicles()
    {
        System.out.print("\n Total Vehicle on the campus: " + listLength);
    }//end of total vehicles

    public String toString() {
        String str = "List:\nhead -> [ ";
        Node current = head;

        while (current != null) {
            str = str + current + (current == tail ? " ] <- tail" : ", ");
            current = current.link;
        }

        return str;
    }

}//end of linked list
```

Comment: I somewhat understand how you did it. Just some things in your code i have never seen before confused me a bit but i think I got it. a few questions if you don't mind. what is the purpose of **@Override** means how does **array.get(i)** works if the insertFirst functions need three string variables?

Comment: Make some research before you ask questions. @Override is used to override an existing function. So you replace a function that already exists inside that class.

Comment: He declared 2 functions called insertFirst(), one function takes 3 parameter the other one only 1. So if you call insertFirst() with one parameter it will call the function that takes one and if you call it with three it will call the function that takes three parameter.

Comment: I think its confusing that dquijada creates a class that is called LinkedList, which already exists in java.util.* Would a different name not be better?

Comment: @JosiahFrancis the `@Override` annotation makes it so it overrides the method of the class/interface it extends/implements. So when you do ".compare()" it calls it instead of the one of the superclass. I also overloaded the method "insertFirst", meaning that: depending on the parameters it will call one or the other

Comment: @Alexanus I agree that it's not a good name, but I maintained it from the OPs code, just modified it a bit (but didn't want to change the name so it would be clearer)